# BibTeX: Capitalization of note field: plain.bst vs. amsplain.bst

Tags: bibtex, capitalization

The `plain` bibtex style uses a period before outputting the note field, while `amsplain` uses a comma. None of them handle capitalization of the note field.

For instance, consider `test.bib` containing

```
@Article{test,
  author =   {An Author},
  title =    {A Title},
  journal =  {A journal},
  year =     2016,
  volume =   42,
  pages =    {42--43},
  note =     {with an appendix},
}
```

With `\bibliographystyle{plain}`, the output will be

> [1] An Author. A title. A journal, 42:42–43, 2016. with an appendix.

With `\bibliographystyle{amsplain}`, the output will be

> [1] An Author, A title, A journal 42 (2016), 42–43, with an appendix.

I have a long bib file which I'd like to use with both styles.

I see several possibilities to do this:

1. Change the `bst` file. I do not really want to do that.
2. Add some LaTeX command in front of every `note`, e.g. `note = {\lowercaseforamsstyle With an appendix}` and setting that command in the preamble.

Any suggestions for nicer solutions than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easy, but not too difficult either.

Make a copy of `plain.bst`, naming it `plainnote.bst`, and add

```
FUNCTION {format.note}
{ note empty$
    { "" }
    { note #1 #1 substring$ "u" change.case$
      note #2 note text.length$ #1 - substring$ *}
  if$
}
```

somewhere, I put it just before `FUNCTION {format.authors}`.

The purpose of the function is to get the first character of the `note` field and to change it into uppercase; then the rest of the field is concatenated.

Then change all appearances of `note output` into

```
format.note output
```

Here's the `.bbl` file I get from your example, using `\bibliographystyle{plainnote}`, with no change.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{test}
An~Author.
\newblock A title.
\newblock {\em A journal}, 42:42--43, 2016.
\newblock With an appendix.

\end{thebibliography}
```

The alternative is to use uppercase in the note field and change `amsplain.bst` in the similar way, but with `"l" change.case$` for turning the first letter lowercase.

Without going into modifying `.bst` files, you can input the note field as

```
note = {\lowercaseforams With an appendix}
```

and define, in the preamble,

```
\newcommand\lowercaseforams{%
  \ifdefined\MR\expandafter\MakeLowercase\fi
}
```

This exploits the fact that `amsplain.bst` defines `\MR`. Without relying on this, you can do

```
%\newcommand{\lowercaseforams}{\MakeLowercase}
\newcommand{\lowercaseforams}{}
```

and switch the comments on and off as needed.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using `@Preamble{"\newcommand\lowercaseforams{\ifdefined\MR\expandafter\MakeLowercase\fi}"}` in the Bibfile.